# How can we write custom lint rule for our app?

Tags: android

I used this link to create our own custom lint rules
[link](https://android.jlelse.eu/writing-custom-lint-rules-and-integrating-them-with-android-studio-inspections-or-carefulnow-c54d72f00d30)

then create `WrongLayoutDetector.class` to detect wrong layout name

```
private val allowedPrefixes = listOf("activity_", "view_", "fragment_", "dialog_", "bottom_sheet_", "adapter_item_", "divider_", "space_", "popup_window_")

val ISSUE_WRONG_LAYOUT_NAME = Issue.create("WrongLayoutName",
    "Layout names should be prefixed accordingly.",
    "The layout file name should be prefixed with one of the following: ${allowedPrefixes.joinToString()}. This will improve consistency in your code base as well as enforce a certain structure.",
        CORRECTNESS, 7, WARNING,
    Implementation(WrongLayoutNameDetector::class.java, RESOURCE_FILE_SCOPE))

class WrongLayoutNameDetector : LayoutDetector() {
  override fun visitDocument(context: XmlContext, document: Document) {
    val modified = allowedPrefixes.map {
      val resourcePrefix = context.project.resourcePrefix()
          .forceUnderscoreIfNeeded()

      if (resourcePrefix != it) resourcePrefix + it else it
    }

    val doesNotStartWithPrefix = modified.none { context.file.name.startsWith(it) }
    val notEquals = modified.map {
        it.dropLast(1) // Drop the trailing underscore.
    }.none { context.file.name == "$it.xml" }

    if (doesNotStartWithPrefix && notEquals) {
      context.report(ISSUE_WRONG_LAYOUT_NAME, document, context.getLocation(document), "Layout does not start with one of the following prefixes: ${modified.joinToString()}")
    }
  }
}

private fun String.forceUnderscoreIfNeeded() = if (isNotEmpty() && !endsWith("_")) plus("_") else this

fun Project.resourcePrefix() = if (isGradleProject) computeResourcePrefix(gradleProjectModel).orEmpty() else ""
```

IssueRegistry class

```
class IssueRegistry : IssueRegistry() {
    override val issues: List<Issue>
        get() = listOf( ISSUE_WRONG_LAYOUT_NAME,ISSUE_ALERT_DIALOG_USAGE)

    override val api: Int = com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.CURRENT_API
}
```

build gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    // For a description of the below dependencies, see the main project README
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.2.0-rc02"
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.2.0-rc02"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.2.0-rc02"
    testCompile "com.android.tools.lint:lint-tests:26.2.0-rc02"
    testCompile "com.android.tools:testutils:26.2.0-rc02"
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

jar {
    manifest {
        // Only use the "-v2" key here if your checks have been updated to the
        // new 3.0 APIs (including UAST)
        attributes("Lint-Registry-v2": "com.example.lint.checks.IssueRegistry")
    }
}
```

now in our code

lint.xml file

```
<lint>
     <!-- Change the severity of hardcoded strings to "error" -->
    <issue id="WrongLayoutName"
  severity="warning"  />
</lint>
```

and in app gradle file

```
 lintOptions {
        tasks.lint.enabled = true
        abortOnError true
        lintConfig file('./code_quality_tools/lint.xml')
    }
```

now i am analyze code but not getting any warning like WrongLayoutName.
How could i implement custom lint rules with our app?

if i add   `<issue id="AllCaps" />` in lint file its working fine and getting warning

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the link-check module in your dependency:

If you have this structure:

```
lint-check
   -- build.gradle
app
   -- build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app'
include ':lint-checks'
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    lintChecks project(':lint-checks')
}
```